# How do I format using standardjs in coc.nvim?

Tags: standardjs, coc.nvim

I need to use StandardJs for linting a TS project's files. I use coc.nvim. I've read multiple SO posts and [articles](https://standardjs.com/#vim) about setting up coc.nvim with ESLint to get it to lint on fileSave, but I cannot find anything with regards to StandardJS.

How can I get coc.nvim to automatically format JS and TS files I write using coc.nvim after saving?